# NoSQL - документ

Tags: redis, nosql, cassandra, couchdb

Всем привет.

1. Документ в NoSQL - это строка или таблица, в сравнении с SQL?
2. Если у меня есть данные типа:

`'img: 'string',

    'time': 'timestamp',
    'rel': { 'sessionid': '_id from type-1' }`

как правильно их структурировать, вот так:

```
{
    '_id': '0001',
     'rev': '1-132asd876876ad87'
    'img': 'string',
    'time': 'timestamp',
    'rel': {
        'sessionid': '_id from type-1'
        'userid': 'userid from type-1'
        }
}
{
    '_id': '0002',
     'rev': '1-1addsasa77asd77ads7'
    'img': 'string',
    'time': 'timestamp',
    'rel': {
        'sessionid': '_id from type-1'
        'userid': 'userid from type-1'
        }
}
 и т.д.
```

или вот так:

```
    {
    '_id': '_design/photo',
     'rev': '2-132asd876876ad87',
     'item':[
           'img': 'path-1',
           'time': 234324324324,
           'rel': {
                 'sessionid': 'sid-1'
                 'userid': 'uid-1'
            },

           'img': 'path to photo',
           'time': 32423413123,
           'rel': {
                 'sessionid': 'sid-2'
                 'userid': 'uid-1'
            },

           'img': 'path to photo',
           'time': 323453543543,
           'rel': {
                 'sessionid': 'sid-1'
                 'userid': 'uid-1'
            },
     ]
}
```

3. Или лучше не выделываться и сделать все по-старинке в SQL?

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Тебе нужно уточнить, какую СУБД используешь и для каких целей нужна эта база, тогда уже можно будет что то посоветовать

Answer (score 0):

1 - это документ в формете json

2 - 2

3 - зависит от задачи, когда то лучше использовать реляционную, когда то то NoSql. Для большинства задач лучше подходит реляционная

Вот статьи с хабра(помогут разобраться): https://habr.com/post/155115/ https://habr.com/post/74144/

Comment: спасибо - понял.
но по вопросу 1 - это документ в формете json - я это знаю. Вероятно я не правильно его задал. 
 это строка или таблица относительно SQL?

Comment: Это большая таблица в которой хранятся пары ключ-значение, то есть какой то id и соответствующий ему документ

Comment: хорошо тогда вопрос, такого рода: получается что для добавления нового елемента в структуру №2 (2-2) мне нужно потянуть весь этот док. в память и добавить в массив ***items*** новое фото? это я к тому что как мне добавить (update) туда новый айтем что бы не тянуть весь док на "клиент".  
Как вариант создать там что то типа тригера. но как - я пока что не понял.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то update делать нельзя, придется вытащить весь документ добавить новый элемент и отправить обрадно в бд. Тут уже скорее всего нужно хранить каждый элемент отдельно, если ты собираешься использовать часто update, а если ты редко будешь делать update, но чаще всего будешь вытаскивать все объекты, то можно и так оставить. В mongodb например вообще нет тригеров. Какая задача для БД?

Comment: **"update делать нельзя, придется вытащить весь документ добавить новый элемент и отправить обрадно в бд"** - ***я так и подумал***
база будет хранить  картинки которые будут постоянно поступать в БД + их описание. если не решим вопрос со стораджем то вероятно что еще и их самих в BINARY но эти картинки временные. Но все равно их будет "очень много". сейчас работаю с Couch DB

Comment: Тогда скорей всего имеет смысл хранить каждую картинку отдельно, при использовании nosql

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за помощь в прояснении ситуации ... ;)

Comment: Да не за что, если что то не ясно, попробуй сформулировать вопрос более точно и задать ещё раз, мб кто то ещё что посоветуте